# How do I create a conditional form value in a Jade template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, express, pug

I have a jade template form in my express project. the form has a form field that is normally blank, but under some circumstances I am pre-populating form fields ). Here is my jade template

```
    input.form-control(type='text', name='name', id='name', value=site.name, autofocus=true)
```

the problem I am having is that sometimes site, and hence site.name is undefined. How do I conditionally place a variable in the value of a form based on it's existence.

Answer (score 0):

- Conditional

use that syntax in the conditional:

```
- var site = { name: 'mysite.com' }
- var user = { description: 'foo bar baz' }
- var authorised = false
#user
  if user.description
    input(type='text' name='name' id='name' value=site.name autofocus='true' checked)
  else if authorised
    h2 Description
    p.description.
  else
    h1 Description
    p.description User has no description
```

- Input

in the input, you should use something like this:

```
- var site = { name: 'mysite.com' }
input(type='text' name='name' id='name' value=site.name autofocus='true' checked)
```

Comment: ahhh I see so you really have to just populate that variable before you render the jade template

Comment: if you want to change in real time you need to use javascript

Comment: So isn't that useful to you? (upvote or mark as solved)